# Batch Memberships Update via Profile - Expiration Date changes not saved due to "Is_override" field not avail in Profile

Tags: civimember, profile, api, searchkit

Thought it is possible to batch update a few membership statuses via profile, wanted to clear Expiration Dates, however changes only partially stick: while Status saves, Expiration Date stays, which creates a paradoxical Current Memberships with Expiration Dates in the past.  Could be possible if "Status Override?" field was available for Profiles I guess.

[image: Profile settings]

Have tried SearchKit however ended up with "An error occurred while attempting to update 206 Memberships." message w/o further details in ConfigAndLogs.
[image: searchkit]

Not sure if API way works either ( akin to  [setting membership status override in bulk update](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/38768/setting-membership-status-override-in-bulk-update) ) , however this is the only way left before entering SQL queries path.

**UPD** API way requires more code to be written, so the fastest would be plain SQL, like this one:

```
UPDATE `civicrm_membership` 
SET `end_date` = NULL, `status_id` = '2', `is_override` = '1'   
WHERE `membership_type_id` = SOME-MEMBERSHIP-TYPE-ID 
AND status_id NOT IN(6,7);
```

where status IDs from your civicrm_membership_status table (6=Cancelled and 7=Deceased in mine)

CiviCRM 5.62, Wordpress.